# php returning null after jquery ajax post of javascript object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

trying to pass a javascript object to php and getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

```
var address = {};

address.whatever = "asdf";

$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/resources/scripts/php/whatever.php',
            data: 'address=' + JSON.stringify(address),
            success: function(returnedData){
                console.log(returnedData);
            },
            error: function (xhr, tst, err) {
                console.log(err);
            },          
        });
```

php

```
$whatever = json_decode($_POST['address']);
 echo json_decode($address);
```

console:
`null`

thanks for any insight!

Comment: made a few stupid mistakes. nevermind. thanks for looking.

Comment: In your PHP code, did you mean `echo json_encode($s);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$whatever = json_decode($_POST['address']);
echo json_decode($address);
```

should be:

```
 echo $_POST["whatever"];
```

and

```
data: 'address=' + JSON.stringify(address),
```

should be:

```
 data: JSON.stringify(address),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/resources/scripts/php/whatever.php',
            data: {address : address},
            success: function(returnedData){
                console.log(returnedData);
            },
            error: function (xhr, tst, err) {
                console.log(err);
            }          
        });
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/resources/scripts/php/whatever.php',
        data: {'address' : JSON.stringify(address)},
        success: function(returnedData){
            console.log(returnedData);
        },
        error: function (xhr, tst, err) {
            console.log(err);
        },          
    });
```

PHP:

```
 $address = json_decode($_POST['address']);
 echo $address['whatever'];
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to JSON.stringify. jQuery takes care of it for you.

With:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/resources/scripts/php/whatever.php',
    data: {address: address},
    success: function(returnedData){
        console.log(returnedData);
    },
    error: function (xhr, tst, err) {
        console.log(err);
    },
});
```

You can use:

```
echo $_POST['address']['whatever'] // output asdf
```

Comment: really? Thanks! Even in IE? (I read early versions have trouble with JSON). Also, how come then using stringify doesn't like put an additional shell around it? If that makes sense..

Comment: Yes. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below). Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/